# New Order transactional email template nonexistant?

Tags: magento-1.8, email, email-templates, transactional

I've tried to load the 'New Order' email template into my transactional emails and there is no result, and no error message.

The other ones seem to be working fine

**Can anyone advise on this strange issue?**

Comment: Check whether there is a translation in your magento.

Comment: Can you specify further please?

Comment: Magento has the emails here: `app/locale/<language_CODE>/template/email` so there should be an email with the name `order_new.html` and `order_new_guest.html`

Comment: Thanks, I found the template and moved it into /email from /email/sales

The script loads but the html doesnt come in

Comment: Sorry, the sales mails lay in sales, so this should work. To fix this, just copy the content of the file. If you want to know what goes wrong, turn on xdebug and dig into the code

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, just copy the content of the file.

If you want to know what goes wrong, turn on xdebug and dig into the code